# Update Git repository with new full release

Tags: git

I've inherited a large set of software and am trying to implement version control with Git. I have 2 releases of this software and would like to create the Git repository on the earlier release and then add all the changes from the new release, but I don't know which files have changed (there are hundreds of files), so I can't stage them individually. I've tried creating the repository, then copying all the new files (with the same name and directory structure of course), but Git shows them as if I had just added all the code even if it matches the old code. Not too surprising, but I'm hoping I'm missing some magic step and somebody knows what that step is. Thanks.

Comment: _"GIT shows them as if I had just added all the code even if it matches the old code"_ - this is not how git works, it tracks content changes. Use `git diff` to check what actually has changed in the files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two folder with the files for each release, create a git repo anywhere else and do:

```
cd /anywhere/else
git init .

# check your name/email
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

(if those commands output are empty, do set them to the appropriate value)

```
Import:

git --work-tree=/path/to/release1 add .
git commit -m  "First release"

git --work-tree=/path/to/release2 add .
git commit -m  "Second release"
```

Git will detect automatically which files have changed/been deleted or modified between each import.